# Nested loops in columns VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, loops, nested-loops

I need to take the data from column A and add each value to the schools in row 1.It should all become just columns. The input is:

[Input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjWbN.png)

and the output I need is something like this:

```
School               SERVICE     Number of  Price
Granbacka skola      Computer    1          500
Granbacka skola      Ipads       25         600
Granbacka skola      Iphone      0          700
Granbacka skola      Ipad Swap   0          800
Granbacka skola      Iphone Swap 0          900
Granbacka skola      Service     0          1000
Bagartorps förskola  Computer    1          500
Bagartorps förskola  Ipads       0          600
Bagartorps förskola  Iphone      5          700
Bagartorps förskola  Ipad Swap   4          800
Bagartorps förskola  Iphone Swap 0          900
Bagartorps förskola  Service     1          1000
Ekensbergs skola     Computer    2          500
Ekensbergs skola     Ipads       0          600
Ekensbergs skola     Iphone      33         700
Ekensbergs skola     Ipad Swap   0          800
Ekensbergs skola     Iphone Swap 0          900
Ekensbergs skola     Service     0          1000
Frösunda skola       Computer    3          500
Frösunda skola       Ipads       0          600
Frösunda skola       Iphone      0          700
Frösunda skola       Ipad Swap   0          800
Frösunda skola       Iphone Swap 2          900
Frösunda skola       Service     0          1000
```

The code will be applied to several workbooks and sheets, where the number of services and schools can be a diffrent.

I've tried writing and search but cant fin anything that solves my problem.
Thank you!

//M

Edit 2017-05-30 - Changed the input and output example to clarify what I need to accomplish.

Comment: How did you come up with the 5 in the first row? "Number of: 5"

Comment: It should be 1, I have edited the post now

Comment: Am still not understanding. Can you do it for all the schools? I want to see the complete output

Comment: I have now updated the complete output that I need, hope it makes it clearer what I need

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code,

```
Sub loopcols()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, x As Long, y As Long
i = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column() - 2
j = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row() - 1
Sheets.Add.Name = "newSheet"
x = 1
y = 1
For k = 1 To i * j
    If k Mod j <> 0 Then
        Sheets("newSheet").Cells(k, 1) = Cells(1, 2 + x)
        Sheets("newSheet").Cells(k, 2) = Cells(y + 1, 1)
        Sheets("newSheet").Cells(k, 4) = Cells(y + 1, 2)
        y = y + 1
    Else
        Sheets("newSheet").Cells(k, 1) = Cells(1, 2 + x)
        Sheets("newSheet").Cells(k, 2) = Cells(y + 1, 1)
        Sheets("newSheet").Cells(k, 4) = Cells(y + 1, 2)
        x = x + 1
        y = 1
    End If
Next k
x = 1
y = 3
For k = 1 To i * j
    Sheets("newSheet").Cells(k, 3) = Cells(x + 1, y)
    x = x + 1
    If k Mod j = 0 Then
        x = 1
        y = y + 1
    End If
Next k
Sheets("newSheet").Rows(1).Insert
Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, 1) = "School"
Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, 2) = Cells(1, 1)
Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, 3) = "Number Of:"
Sheets("newSheet").Cells(1, 4) = Cells(1, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I might have been unclear but it is not exactly what I need. School 1 has a name, ex Bergsskolan and so does the service, such as Ipad Swap Service. So each school name need to be written and each service need to be written, not referred to as a number. The outcome will be loaded into an ERP-system, therefore all data must have exact names. I update my question with this information! Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: @Matthei Try modifying my code. Let me know if you need help

Comment: I have tried and some of it was I able to change.

I managed to get each school to appear the number of services times:
'Sheets("newSheet").Cells(k + 1, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, y + 3)                               

But I can't figure out the service part:
'Sheets("newSheet").Range(Cells(k + 1, 3), Cells(k + 1 + i, 3)) = 'Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + 1, 2)'

Each service appear 1 time and then it is blank until next loop of schools and then it comes again.I need to get the code to take each service the number of schools there is and then loop to the next one and so on.

Comment: @Matthei Try this out now.